# What should the summary count on an "active filter" button be representing?

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, filter, faceted-search

Often, in facetted filtering experiences, on mobile, the filters are tucked offscreen. To indicate that the current view is being filtered, often the filter button is presented with a number indicating how many active filters are applied. ex:  [ Filters (2) ]

This number is inconsistent from retailer to retailer. It can be either:

- the number of selected filter values
- the number of filter categories with filter values selected in them.

### **Amazon represents the number of filter categories selected:**

- Brand: Intel & AMD
- Shipping: Free
- Cores: 2, 4 & 8

[image: Amazon]

### **Walmart represents the number of filter values selected:**

- Brand: Apple & Sony
- Shipping: Free
- Colour: Grey, Pink, White

[image: Walmart]

As far as I'm concerned - the biggest usability gain comes from having *anything* indicating an active filter state - the exact count isn't that essential.

**Pro Filter Category**

- Numbers past a certain point don't really matter
- It may be more important to know the number of categories, rather than values
- When you open the filter button, you tend to see categories - tap 3, see 3 selected things

**Pro Filter Value**

- Every time the filter changes, the number is guaranteed to change
- It's a simple sum and may match user mental models.

From my audit around the web, it's about 50/50 and I guess either one works, but is there any other arguments that can work in favour of one or the other approach?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, whenever I tested this functionality I learned that the number in the Filter button is always expected to represent the number of **filters applied**.

When the user reaches the list/grid of products they usually expect a *sort* and a *filter* button. The filter button has no number next to it initially. After one filter is applied, the number (1) is displayed inside the button. I thought this was pretty much standard by now.

Answer (score 0):

I think more useful information is how effective was current filter, i.e. what is percentage of found results relatively to total unfiltered amount. For example:

*Filtered 10%*

or

*Filter (10%)*

Comment: I appreciate your new take on this, but I couldn't find a single retailer using this pattern.


Given that: "[Users spend most of their time on other sites. This means that users prefer your site to work the same way as all the other sites they already know.](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/end-of-web-design/)"

I would be highly suspect of introducing a unique interaction pattern.

Comment: You are welcome. But nothing is absolute in this World (Wide Web) :) I think both 'usual' variants are not informative thus are unusable. They looks like debugging message used by developer. Remove them with just `Set`/`Not set` wording and this change nothing in usability. So be the first to add some sense to digits. Good luck! And thank you for the link.